# How can I check which user uploaded apk file in Google Play?

Tags: android, upload, console, apk, playback

I'm using Google Play Developer Console in a large company with multiple apps and many users that have permission to upload new apk versions. If someone changes the Google Play app description or title, we can find out by checking the activity log. But I don't see an option to find out who uploaded new version of the app (and that seems more important than description). Is there a way to check history of uploads and users who uploaded the apk? This looks like a big security concern, because someone can upload some harmful version and get away with it.

Answer (score 1):

I think when item is **APK**  and Change is **Added** in activity log, then we can consider it a new upload. see image

[image]

Comment: Yes, I thought that too. But there is no info on new version releases there, and I checked it with owner account. There is version history for every app and dates when the rollout was updated, but unfortunately there is no user name associated with releases.